# Form validation with SELECT field using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Jquery Isn't alerting me when their is no value selected from the Rating form.
Would it be because selected="selected" is actually being seen as a value to jquery ?

```
  <label for="rating">Rating</label>
    <select id="rating" name="rating" />
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Rating</option>
        <option value="Terrible">Terrible</option>
        <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
        <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
        <option value="Good">Good</option>
        <option value="Excellent">Excellent</option>
       </select>


      $(document).ready(function(){

        // No value for movie_title
        if ($('#movie_title').val() == "" ) {
            alert ("No Film");
        }

        // No Value for actor
        if ($('#leading_name').val() == "") {
            alert ("No actor");
        }

        // No value for rating
        if ($('#rating').val() == "") {
            alert ("No Rating");
        }

        //No value for review
        if ($('#review').val() == "") {
            alert ("No review");
        }

    // Focus on first form field.
        $("input:text:visible:first").focus();

   })
```

Comment: Oh I'm selecting the wrong id review/rating. Actually that's also wrong... been a long day.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the default value will be the text if no value is specified.

Give a value of `0` to your default option and check against that:

```
<option selected="selected" value=0 disabled="disabled">Select a Rating</option>
```

Comment: just to point out: there are some plugins for jquery (like jquery ui), which needs the value attribute exigent to work

Comment: Is this how you would check the value
            if ($('#rating').val() == 0) {
                alert ("No Rating");
            }

Answer (score 1):

`$('#rating').val()` returns `null`:

http://jsfiddle.net/KFpFq/

Adding a `value` attribute doesn't appear to work in Chrome, though checking for `null` does.

```
console.log($('#rating').val()); //null
console.log($('#rating').val() == "0"); //false
console.log($('#rating').val() == null); //true
```

Comment: Never knew such a website existed. Wicked

Answer (score 0):

You could use the native `selectedIndex` to find the index of the first selection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

```
if($('#rating').get(0).selectedIndex === 0){alert("first item")}
```

Comment: It's in the DOM level-1 spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980 "The ordinal index of the selected option. The value -1 is returned if no element is selected. If multiple options are selected, the index of the first selected option is returned."

Comment: (the .get(0) gives you the first raw dom element from jQuery selection - http://api.jquery.com/get/ )